# Error when attempting to copy files w/ scp

Tags: 14.04, scp

I'm connecting to an Ubuntu instance, running some Apache/JMeter tests, and *attempting* to use scp to grab the log files from said tests.

I connect w/ the following command:

```
ssh my-host.amazonaws.com -l my-username
```

I'm able to connect, and I'm able to run the tests.  However, I've yet to perform an scp command without an error.

I'm using the following command:

```
scp my-username@my-machine-address.amazonaws.com:~/my-file-name.jtl ./
```

I immediately get the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any idea what the issue could be?  I have rights to connect to the machine in the first place.  Also, the "my-username" username is shared by a couple test users, and others are able to perform the scp command without issue.

Edit: here is my output from attempting the scp command w/ the -v argument:

```
my-username@ip-xx-xx-xxx-xx:~$ scp -v 
    my-username@my-host.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/jmeter.log ./
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host my-host.amazonaws.com, 
    user ubuntu, command scp -v -f /home/ubuntu/jmeter.log
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to my-host.amazonaws.com [xx.xx.xxx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 
    OpenSSH_6.6.1p1     Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* 
    compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA     xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
debug1: Host 'my-host.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host
    key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xxx
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_yyy
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_abcde
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_zzzzzzz
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Here is the verbose logging from my initial SSH connection:

```
$ ssh -v my-host.amazonaws.com -l ubuntu
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to my-host.amazonaws.com [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1         
    Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA     xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
debug1: Host 'my-host.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to my-host.amazonaws.com ([xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-95-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: You may get some insight if you re-run the command, adding the `-v` (verbose) flag

Comment: I did that earlier.  I'll add it to the question.  Thanks

Comment: When you say you're able to connect to the machine, how do you mean? Using ssh or some other way?

Comment: @MarkSmith - I'm using SSH; I've edited my question w/ that info.  Thanks

Comment: Try: `scp -r -i my-username@my-machine-address.amazonaws.com:~/my-file-name.jtl ./`

Comment: Post the same verbose log from the `ssh` that you used. Are you sure you have correct hostname and username?

Comment: @Jakuje - I've added verbose log from the ssh connection.

Comment: Do you run the command on the same machine? It is using different OpenSSH versions. What is the machine you run the commands on? `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xxx` is not `/c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not running both commands from the same machine or from the same user.

One output says /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa is used, other says /c/Users/jdoe/.ssh/id_rsa

So you are probably using wrong key in the scp case, coming from wrong directory.